# autocomplete feature in combobox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, combobox

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ddlfrom" runat="server"                                     
   MaxLength="0" 
   style="display: inline;" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"                                          
   ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalValue"
```

I am using .net 4.0 version.
I have a combobox I want the autocomplete feature along with filtering of elements... I have connected my combobox to the database now I just want to implement autocomplete feature...how to do it...??
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

Comment: Please use this link. [http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx) Hope it help.

Comment: @kostasch. but it only match items that start with the first user-typed character..i want to match it from anywhere in the text..

Answer (score 0):

You can check JQuery plugin for autocomplete functionality, its really easy
[JQuery AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: but i have list of items in my database...i am populating the combobox from database...

Comment: You can get the list from database either by webservice or through AJAX call from your source code and then bind it with JQuery autocomplete dropdownlist.